# Elasticsearch cluster doesn't work on Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

The docker-compose YAML below file brings up a 3-node Elasticsearch cluster when used with the `docker compose` command.  That is OK for debug but I want to move to deployment, so I want to deploy on a swarm where the containers can run on different systems.

So

```
docker compose up
```

works, but

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml p3es
```

creates the same containers (although on different systems) and the overlay network, but the elasticsearch instances are not able to talk to each other via port 9300.  So a master never gets assigned and although elasticsearch responds to HTTP requests they just error out.

In the logs the following exception/stack trace appears on each container:

```
p3es_es01.1.sv26uqp4i4s3@carbon    | "stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [es03][10.0.12.9:9300][internal:cluster/coordination/join]",
p3es_es01.1.sv26uqp4i4s3@carbon    | "Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [es01][10.0.0.53:9300] connect_exception",
(etc)
```

The cause of the exception turns out to be:

```
p3es_es01.1.sv26uqp4i4s3@carbon    | "Caused by: java.io.IOException: connection timed out: 10.0.0.53/10.0.0.53:9300",
```

So here are some things I have tried:

1. I invoke a shell on one of the containers.   I can ping each of the other containers.   I can also do a `curl -XGET` on each of the containers and get a response from port 9200.
2. If I do a curl -XGET on port 9300 on one of the containers I get a "Not an HTTP Port" message.   But at least it was able to resolve the address.
3. Docker stack likes to put prefixes on names for objects.   So if you name a network xyz the network actually gets named project_xyz.   So I changed the environment variables that tell elasticsearch who is part of the cluster to include the project name prefix.   No luck.

I've run out of ideas.  Any suggestions?

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.2
    environment:
      - HOSTNAME=es01
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - es9300
    volumes:
      - nfs-es01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.2
    environment:
      - HOSTNAME=es02
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - es9300
    volumes:
      - nfs-es02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.5.2
    environment:
      - HOSTNAME=es03
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    networks:
      - es9300
    volumes:
      - nfs-es03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

volumes:
  nfs-es01:
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=10.2.0.1,rw,nfsvers=4,local_lock=all
      device: :/sbn/process3/elasticsearch01
  nfs-es02:
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=10.2.0.1,rw,nfsvers=4,local_lock=all
      device: :/sbn/process3/elasticsearch02
  nfs-es03:
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=10.2.0.1,rw,nfsvers=4,local_lock=all
      device: :/sbn/process3/elasticsearch03

networks:
  es9300:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, Elasticsearch discovery gets confused when Docker provides it with multiple overlay networks.  So the directive:

```
ports:
  - 9200:9200
```

causes each `es0*` service to be on the ingress overlay network *in addition* to the overlay network specified (in this case `es9300`).   For some reason when Elasticsearch is running in the containers, it gets the wrong IP address when resolving the service/DNS `es01`.

I haven't determined why that is, but removing the ports directive to publish port 9200 resolves the issue.

Hopefully this posting will help someone encountering the same issue.

Comment: I have run into this exact same issue. Did you find a workaround? I would love to know how to access the cluster with a published port.

Comment: @designermonkey sorry I ultimately bailed.   I built my own ES cluster out of KVM hosted VMs.